# I am trying to create NxM character array in which 'N' would be dynamic and 'M' would be static

Tags: c, string, dynamic

I have this problem of anagrams, but my problem is kinda different. The problem is I am asking for input from user in a string form, its a 2D char array and breaking them in to word by word, for example :

INPUT :

```
XDG LMN OPI
STOP                           //STOP to stop taking the input
```

and I want my output in this form :

OUTPUT :

```
xdg
lmn
opi                        //converting into lowercase
```

Now, I can do this by looking up for space and when there is space put `'\0'` and increase N and make M equals to 0 in static char array.

Another solution is I'll create dynamic char array and do all the maths.

But, here in my problem I am not sure about the number of rows but I am pretty sure about the length of columns, max 20. So, I wondered that if I can only create dynamic rows which grows till I'll not find NULL in my 2D array.

Here is my Function :

```
void TransformString( char input[][LINELEN], size_t counter ) {
size_t Row = 0;
size_t Col = 0;
 char *str[20];
  str =   malloc(Row * sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < counter ; i++ ){
      char *string = input[i];

        while( *string != '\0' ){   
          if( !(isspace(*string)) ){
            *string = tolower(*string);
            str[Row][Col++] = *string;printf("RR : %d C : %d\n",Row,Col);

        } if(*string == ' ') { printf("C : %d\n",Col);
              str[Row][Col] = '\0' ;
              Row++;
              str = malloc(Row * sizeof(char)) ; printf("Row: %d\n",Row);
              Col = 0;
        }
       string++;
      } 
      str[Row][Col] = '\0' ;
      Row++;
          *str = malloc (Row * sizeof(char) );
          Col = 0;
        }
       } // end of function
```

As for dynamic we take `char ** str;` so for this I have taken `char *str[20];`

This code is not working according to my need. Please look in to this and give me the logic where I am wrong.

Comment: `This code is not working according to my need.` Did you consider explaining _why not_?

Comment: while reading first part of the input string, its entering in the if(!isspace( *string) ) and copying the characters to my new str array, then reading the blank space and entering in another if (*string == '  ') , putting nul character in string, incrementing Row, and making Col to 0 , but after that its not entering in the if(!isspace()) block, Sir, I have already placed the printf(), you can check if you want to.. thanks @underscore_d

Comment: you want `char (*str)[20];` instead of `char *str[20];`

Comment: Its not printing, I have one function which is working for others 2D char array but for this its just running blank. Please help. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: and what's the difference between `char (*str)[20];` and `char *str[20];` ??? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `char (*str)[20];` : `str` is pointer to `char[20]`, `char *str[20];` : `str` is array of pointer. `str` has 20 element (pointer to char).

Comment: The first is a pointer to a 20 byte char array, the second is a array of 20 char pointers.
But your whole script is buggy. If you allocate Row char pointer, you have only the pointers. You have to allocate also the memory for every one of this pointers.

Comment: I am using `malloc()' , I believe, if its not allocating memory than what's it doing ? @Holger

Comment: But why its running blank ?? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @DeveshPratap You are not output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `realloc` and char `(*str)[20]` instead of char `*str[20]`
example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINELEN   96
#define COLMAXLEN 20

void TransformString(char input[][LINELEN], size_t counter ) {
    size_t Row = 0;
    char (*str)[COLMAXLEN] = NULL;

    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < counter ; i++ ){
        char *string = input[i];

        while( *string != '\0' ){
            while(isspace(*string))
                ++string;//skip spaces
            if(!*string) break;

            void *temp;//char (*temp)[COLMAXLEN];
            if((temp = realloc(str, (Row+1) * sizeof(*str))) == NULL){//expand
                fprintf(stderr, "malloc error at %s\n", __func__);
                free(str);
                return ;
            }
            str = temp;//update if realloc is success

            size_t Col = 0;
            while(*string && !isspace(*string) && Col < COLMAXLEN -1){
                str[Row][Col++] = tolower(*string++);
            }
            str[Row++][Col] = '\0';
        }
    }
    for(size_t r = 0; r < Row; ++r)
        puts(str[r]);
    free(str);
}

int main(void){
    char input[100][LINELEN] = {
        "XDG LMN OPI",
        "STOP"
    };
    size_t count_line = 1;

    TransformString(input, count_line );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got my error but one more question, why you are using temp, instead of str ?  any specific reasons for that ? thanks for help.

Comment: `realloc` might not be able to secure a new area.

Comment: Got it I read it when your made it identical , its now pointer for realloc. THANKS.. cheers!!!